# Copying a variable contained in cell into another cell

Tags: vba, excel, variables, find

I have this text in cell A2:

> 2018 / Erbe / France / Beflubu, zolin, Benflu, sate, furon, Bensu /
>   Show only: **VARIABLE** / Value ($ m): 169.46

I am trying to copy only the value of **VARIABLE** into cell D2.

Everything in this cell can vary, the only fixed things are `"Show Only:"`, `"Value ($):"`, all the `/` characters, and `.` (in the number part of the value)

I am trying to do it in VBA.

Comment: The line from 2018 to 169.46 is in cell A2 completely? An you want to split the string to only get the parts in between `ly: ` and ` /Value` ?

Comment: Have you tried using Regular Expressions? Please show the VBA code you have written. Do not ask someone else to write code for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the code below, explanations inside the code's comments:

```
Option Explicit

Sub ExtractAfterShowOnly()

Dim WordsArr() As String
Dim i As Long
Dim MatchString As String

' use Split to read each section between "/" as arra element
WordsArr = Split(Range("A2").Value2, " / ")

' loop through array
For i = 1 To UBound(WordsArr)

    ' if there's a match, get the text inside and exit the loop
    If WordsArr(i) Like "*Show only:*" Then
        MatchString = WordsArr(i)
        Exit For
    End If
Next i

' Use Mid function to show the string after "Show only:"
MsgBox Mid(MatchString, Len("Show only:") + 1)

End Sub
```